# Is there a Latin equivalent for "FYI" (for your information)?

Tags: english, word-usage

I understand that the Latin translation of "for your information" is "ad tuo nuntio", but is the acronym ATN used?

Comment: Depends on context. Finnish, for example, is a modern language that has no exact equivalent of the English "FYI" across all use contexts. (And it wouldn't get abbreviated the same way.) Did you have a specific context in mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Ad tuo nuntio* is not grammatical, and *ad tuum nuntium*, the grammatically correct version, doesn't mean "for your information" anyway.

The Romans weren't big on acronyms, but one that does pop up in the modern world is N. B. (or NB, N.B., nb, etc.), which is an abbreviation for *nota bene*, or "note well," used to indicate when something is of importance and should be noted and remembered.

A more medieval version is apparently [D. M.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene), *dignum memoria*, "worthy to remember."

I don't think the two are always exact, but they overlap enough in both meaning and context that, depending on what you want to say, you could easily use NB instead of FYI.

Comment: "The Romans weren't big on acronyms" ... say what??

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel You have a few examples, but nothing even close to getting to USDA / USAF / FBI / FDA / ttyl / tmi / lmao, etc. I say that more to temper expectations that they would have had any sort of acronym for what we have. NB this is different from inscriptions' abbreviations!

Comment: That makes sense, it's just a little strange to read the Romans weren't big on acronyms when the average Roman coin reads something like *TI CLAVD CAESAR AVG P M TR P XI IMP P P COS V* etc. ;-)

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I think most distinguish between those types and acronyms proper. They definitely abbreviate their words (mostly in inscriptions and on coins), but you don't really see that in a literary text. The most is perhaps S. P. D. with letters (which is often written out in some way) and of course SQPR. The beginnings were there, but I just can't picture Cicero writing, "Oh, and [FYI], Caesar is way over the line here [imvho], but [ig] we gotta go with it anyway [iykwim]."

Comment: Note that FYI is used to show that information is simply being presented and that no response or action is requested or expected. That is *not* what "N.B." means.